# Select a line in Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

How can I programatically select a specific line and move my cursor to it? (I know how to scroll to it, but I was not able to figure out how to select it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it like in vscode ? :

**Ctrl+G** : [lineNumber] [enter] (go to a specific line number)
(if Ctrl+g did not work on Monaco editor, try to open command palette (Ctrl+Shift+p) and type ":[lineNumber]"

**Ctrl+L** (select whole line)
(Ctrl+Shift+end if it doesn't work)

Comment: My bad, I asked incorrectly; I wanted to ask how to do it programatically. Updating question asap.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `editor.revealLine(lineNumber)` and `editor.setPosition`. First function will show a line in the editor, second one sets the caret to a position. Here is an example in [monaco editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.1#XQAAAAKNBAAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw6z4hdHDvqO0IRKRlt10CsIljquXKAytgVUtsBADjsmEE-rJlEhsOIy7Bp3VIdD_rjJhSXtnpeAVdSKGrGMBf36T62rl4ooyf5DzkVa-ihvn4WPFq0HDWwRjEpCxBWZAVaYtO5rn0Ur_SM4upGidv-tHIBFhZObWx3khOdrmWzd_nmTi9IQ_QVtUlj1EHZ8tL9Uf2KS9pa-NU-yWdN_JHSb_0j6LYnaZsancWR7xejpSpOWbbUUTyS6QQUigrlsOJjumDX3Z5U7pfSZfkSQ8PmYLyeCvyTUE3p4aiEfjz3y3Ftw7pEKVvD-4SYdmdqQQXm6oIymlUbUnNp-vx8c-cQAs9b4qcjFK8BEDxHE7HHQXloQ09kJULBKBqqL1C-he6CF6Y9M5QerPqifhGo_ziw-KhgqGnP7xQFos43Ytx2Tw10Xsx28DJXc4xEUtqOIC8ujisQDvPVpiFbtTkj_-15TOaEDTvl1SLRdDQzKCPyKjanPDe7iN9-Ff5oqBB-YQaFg). Upon loading the editor, cursor will be positioned in the 50th line.

Just in case, here is the code from the playground:

```js
var jsCodeArr = [
    "// ------------------------------",
    "// ------------------------------",
    "function Person(age) {",
    "   if (age) {",
    "       this.age = age;",
    "   }",
    "}",
    "Person.prototype.getAge = function () {",
    "   return this.age;",
    "};",
    "",
    "",
];

jsCodeArr = jsCodeArr.concat(jsCodeArr.slice(0));
jsCodeArr = jsCodeArr.concat(jsCodeArr.slice(0));
jsCodeArr = jsCodeArr.concat(jsCodeArr.slice(0));

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: jsCodeArr.join("\n"),
    language: "javascript",
});

let revealedLine = 50
editor.revealLine(revealedLine);
editor.setPosition({lineNumber: revealedLine, column: 0 })
```